# PYINSTALLER exe not executing - blank terminal closes in 10 seconds

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to make a small Python app to share with non-developers to help automate a small task.

The problem is that the .exe gets generated, and throws a mkl_intel_thread.1.dll issue. I then found the .dll and pasted it in the same folder as the .exe. Now the .exe runs without error, but closes without doing anything.

The python script runs fine and prints these when run separately (as a python file).

I read a lot on similar issues and did try many things, but nothing seems to work. Could anyone help me out, please?

Python code (prints pandas version, and then reads a file to print the number of records) :
I have some additional imports as I want to test their dependency for the actual program where they are used.

```
import requests
from glob import glob
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep


def View_model():
    print(pd.__version__)
    sleep(10)
    data = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv', sep=';')
    data_cnt = len(data)
    print("Total records : ", data_cnt)
    sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    print("started")
    View_model()
    print("completed")
    sleep(10)
```

Pyinstaller .exe generation command(s) :

```
pyinstaller -F --hidden-import 'numpy' --hidden-import 'requests' --hidden-import 'glob' --hidden-import 'bs4' --hidden-import 'pandas' --hidden-import 'datetime' --hidden-import 'time' --add-data "test_data.csv;." check1.py
```

Am I doing something wrong in the process, or is it something non-obvious that is going wrong?

Appreciate any help/leads. Note that I have the .dll file in the same folder as the .exe (see below)

[image]

I am using Miniconda (conda 4.10.3) & have Python 3.9.7

Comment: Trying adding **--windowed** flag and generating .exe file again. And if you want to run your program continuously then run entire program in **infinite** loop

Comment: @Ghanteyyy - tried, but this time nothing ran. the mouse cursor changed to rotating circle, but no terminal opened at all with --windowed flag.

Comment: Try running **windowed exe** file in cmd. You will get error **(if any)** message.